# disconnecting all members from channel discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

```
    try {

    const {guild} = interaction

    const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');

    const channelId = interaction.options.getChannel('channel').id;

    const member2kick = []
    
    member2kick.push(guild?.members.cache.filter(member => member.voice.channelId === channelId).firstKey() as string);

    console.log(member2kick);

    if (channel.type !== ChannelType.GuildVoice) return await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("Błąd").setDescription("Wybrany kanał nie jest kanałem głosowym.").setColor("Red")],
        ephemeral: true,
    });

    member2kick.forEach(member => {
        member.disconnect(channelId);
    });


    await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("Sukces").setDescription("Pomyślnie rozłączono wszystkich użytkowników z kanału głosowego.").setColor("Green")],
        ephemeral: true,
    });

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

I just want to kick everybody from member2kick array. It's correctly getting members from channel but I cannot find way to kick them out

Answer (score 0):

You are missing voice in the **member.disconnect(channelId)**

```js
member2kick.forEach(member => {
    member.voice.disconnect(channelId);
});
```